# Airflow: Storing a Connection in Environment Variables , for databricks connection

Tags: airflow, databricks

I want to store my databricks connection information as an env variable.
as mentioned in

[https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#:~:text=create%20the%20connection.-,Editing%20a%20Connection%20with%20the%20UI,button%20to%20save%20your%20changes](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#:%7E:text=create%20the%20connection.-,Editing%20a%20Connection%20with%20the%20UI,button%20to%20save%20your%20changes).

I am also looking at the following:
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/data-pipelines.html

it says to set the login as : `{“token”: “abc”, “host”:"123"}`
I not sure what to export… does anyone have a clue?? I have the token etc… but what is the export statement?

Comment: I noticed that that guide uses an odd pip install. Its using apache-airflow[databricks] over the provider. can I use the normal provider for this??

Comment: Do you have the connection configured and working but you don't know how to export it to use it as env variable? or you don't know how to create the connection following the `Airflow's URI`?

Comment: I'm not sure in the uri, in the ui you set token for the user , the host string and in extra set the json.  I assume the uri I set the host, use token for user and leave password empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already created the connection from the *Airflow UI*, open a terminal an enter this command: `airflow connections get your_connection_id`.

Example:

```sh
$ airflow connections get sqlite_default
Id: 40
Conn Id: sqlite_default
Conn Type: sqlite
Host: /tmp/sqlite_default.db
Schema: null
Login: null
Password: null
Port: null
Is Encrypted: false
Is Extra Encrypted: false
Extra: {}
URI: sqlite://%2Ftmp%2Fsqlite_default.db
```

The `URI` key has the value you can use to create env variable from. Following this example, would be:

`export AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_PROD_DATABASE='sqlite://%2Ftmp%2Fsqlite_default.db'`

Hope that works for you! [source](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#generating-a-connection-uri)

Comment: I think what was throwing me off was in the UI you set one set the token in the extra section and you put in the user the word token. I was trying to figure out how to replicate that in the URI.. but it turns out you don't.